how to use openpyxl to do 'select' and 'fill down' like in an excel file
I am having a lot of success using openxpyxl to do many operations.  I have a table of dates, numbers and formulas that I insert a new row within the table and enter some easy data (date, name, amount) but I am having trouble with columns that have simple formulas like cell F7 would be '=F6+C7'.  F8 would be '=F7+C8' etc down the table.  When I insert the new (empty) row in the middle of the table, the rows below the insertrow do not get updated with the correct indexed.  For example F24 becomes '=F22+C23' instead of incrementing to '=F23+C24' like it would do if I used an excel 'fill down' in the spreadsheet.  So I am looking for help getting this to work.  I have tried many things shown here:
The basic for statement is:
for row in range(8, finalrow + 1):
    cell_value = f"=F{row-1} + C{row}"
    print("cell formula", cell_value)


I have tried each of these things:

worksheet2.cell(row=row, column=6,value=form_data['cell_value']).font=red_font

worksheet2.array_formulae["F{row}"] = "=F{row-1} + C{row}"

worksheet2.cell(row=row, column=6, value="=F{row-1} + C{row}").font = red_font

worksheet2.cell(row=row, column=6, value=form_data[f"=F{row-1} + C{row}"]).font = red_font

worksheet2[f"C{row}"] = Translator("=B6/$F$3)", origin="c7").translate_formula(f"C{row}")
Comment on 5) - I believe Translator is the command I want to use but I cannot understand how to use it in this case as a fill down.  For this Translator line I received this error message      File "C:\C Drive Documents\Pete Home\Python Excel\bond-input.py", line 292, in 
worksheet2[f"F{row}"] = Translator("=C8+F7)", origin="F7").translate_formula(f"F{row}")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\laroc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\formula\translate.py", line 50, in init
self.tokenizer = Tokenizer(formula)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\laroc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\formula\tokenizer.py", line 53, in init
self._parse()
File "C:\Users\laroc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\formula\tokenizer.py", line 87, in _parse
self.offset += dispatchercurr_char
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\laroc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\formula\tokenizer.py", line 246, in _parse_closer
token = self.token_stack.pop().get_closer()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
IndexError: pop from empty list

I saw this solution using xlswrite package - but xlswriter cannot open up an existing .xlsx file to edit so I cannot use it.


worksheet2.write_formula(f"f{row}", 'cell_value')    # from xlxwriter
So any creative solution doing a 'select' and 'fill down' using openpyxl I would appreciate or any syntax corrections in my attempts would be useful.
BTW - I had no idea how to start with this so I had ChatGPT generate the code which is how I got started and that solution did not work.

Using Translate will be the correct approach.
Let's have a simple example to understand how it works.
Given following source.xlsx:

... following code:
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.formula.translate import Translator

def insert_row_adjust_formulas(ws, row, value):
    ws.insert_rows(row)
    ws[f'C{row}'] = value
    formula_origin = f'F{row-1}' # the formula origin is cell above the inserted cell 
    formula_string = ws[formula_origin].value
    last_row = len(ws['F'])
    for rw in range(row, last_row+1):
        #              Translate the formula string of given formula origin to the new cell
        ws[f'F{rw}'] = Translator(formula_string, formula_origin).translate_formula(f'F{rw}')

wb = load_workbook(filename = 'source.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

insert_row_adjust_formulas(ws, 7, 12.5)

wb.save('result.xlsx')

... leads to following result.xlsx:

The code is self-explanatory and commented where necessary.

Thank you so much for the solution. It works perfectly.  I could not figure out the Translate parameter format to get it to work.
